# How to replace a character in a font with another character

Tags: fonts, software-recommendation

I have a font in TrueType and OpenType format that I really like. I would like to replace one character in this font with another character. Specifically, I would like to make underscores look like spaces. What is the simplest and most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have you researched font editing software?

Comment: I've searched around a bit, but the problem I had was that I don't even know what it needs to support to be able to change characters or what that feature is called.

Comment: Just as a reference for myself and maybe others: There is also a free font editor called [BirdFont](http://birdfont.org/) besides [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I don't know the context you are using it, but the easiest way to do this is to simply use a space instead of an underscore or to find a font that you can use for that specific character and then switch back to your normal font.

That is the easy way. And it makes the most sense if you are using this in a graphical setting, but in heavy content-based text setting with a lot of content and a lot of underscores you might have to go the more difficult route.

The complicated answer is to edit the font using a font editing program. There are some free ones that are worth checking out like [Font Forge](http://fontforge.org/) which works on all operating system, or something like [Font Constructor](http://www.fontconstructor.com/) which is Mac based (I've never used it, but have heard good things from Mac people). I personally use Font Forge because its free, but there are very powerful (and expensive) tools like [FontLab](http://www.fontlab.com/) and [FontCreator](http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html). The downside to being free is that Font forge is pretty difficult to install and if you are afraid of the command line you might be uncomfortable with the process. Although, if you are tech savvy, you might be able to follow the instructions easily.

Once downloaded you would need to upload your font, map the underscore character to a blank character to represent your space, and then repackage the font so you could use it.

I would recommend finding an easy fix to avoid the laborious process of editing the font, but if unavoidable you might have take the steps to edit the font character manually.

Comment: I think I will have to go the complicated way in this case as I can't actually use the space. I want to use this for programming where identifiers don't support the actual space character. Thanks for the tool recommendations! I'll check out them out.

Comment: Do some research, see what's out there, and if you run into any problems, there are a lot of people here that have experience in typography that will help as best they can.

Comment: I just wanted to say that *you are a genious* ☝
Mission acomplished. I am out ☺️