# How to create a symbol for LaTeX using Inkscape by working on font character

Tags: inkscape, font-design, symbols, latex

My purpose is to create the two characters for the imaginary unit `i` and for the Napier number `e` as seen below. Now, the aim is to do this in the Latin Modern Roman Italic font. So in Inkscape, I type the `e` in the correct font, but then I cannot figure out how could I place that white stripes that run all along the border of the letter. Any suggestion? Also, once the symbol is created, how do I make it become a symbol form LaTeX?

[image][image: rrrr][image: rrrr]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Inkscape, you could use something like Times New Roman Italic, type an *e*, and convert to outlines using *Path > Object to Path*.  Then add a stroke with the Pen Tool, convert the stroke to a path using *Path > Stroke to Path*, and then select both shapes, and join them using *Path > Union*.  Then export it as a plain SVG, or as a PDF.

[image]

Comment: Tanks for your answer, that was right what I was looking for... I just don't understand how to add a stroke with the pen tool, what does it mean? I'm really at the beginning, sorry for the ignorance!

Comment: I mean how did you manage to get that perfect shape over the original e? DId you do with free hand drawing? Or is there some trick?

Comment: I used the Pen Tool and its Bézier curves to make it perfect.  That's a skill in itself.  If you are interested in learning how to use the tool, try the [Bézier game](http://bezier.method.ac/)

Comment: You were much precious, I'm sorry I can't vote you up!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the font file itself and there's a number of tools you can use for that to either update an existing character or add a new one based on an existing character. See these questions:

- [How to replace a character in a font with another character](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19554)
- [A font for mathematical notation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62809)